# parsing JSON with GSON, classes issue

Tags: java, json, gson

I have problem with parsing JSON with GSON.

JSON:

```
{ "data" : [ { "agent" : "Something",
    "browser" : "app_j2me",
    "campaign" : [ { "banner_type" : "mweb",
          "campaign_type" : "cpc",
          "cid" : "3",
          "contentid" : "49fee4",
          "ecpm" : "0.0804"
        },
        { "banner_type" : "mweb",
          "campaign_type" : "cpc",
          "cid" : "22",
          "contentid" : "1234",
          "ecpm" : "0.1"
        }
      ],
    "cntr" : "th",
    "imgsize" : "216x36",
    "ip" : "123.123.123.123",
    "partnerid" : 8959,
    "url_click" : "...",
    "url_img" : "...",
    "url_show" : "...",
    "version" : "2"
  } ],
 "error" : null
}
```

Java part:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Json j = gson.fromJson(res, Json.class);
System.out.println(j);
```

Classes:

```
class Json {

public Data d;
public Error r;

public String toString() {
    return "Json [url_click=" + d.url_click
            + ", url_img=" + d.url_img
            + ", url_show=" + d.url_show
            + ", imgsize=" + d.imgsize
            + ", cntr=" + d.cntr
            + ", ip=" + d.ip
            + ", version=" + d.version + "]";
}
}

class Data {

public static String url_click;
public String url_img;
public String url_show;
public String imgsize;
public String cntr;
public String ip;
public String version;
public String browser;
public String agent;
public List<Campaign> campaign;

public String toString() {
    return "Data [url_click=" + url_click
            + ", url_img=" + url_img
            + ", url_show=" + url_show
            + ", imgsize=" + imgsize
            + ", cntr=" + cntr
            + ", ip=" + ip
            + ", version=" + version + "]";
}
}

class Campaign {

public String banner_type;
public String campaign_type;
public String cid;
public String contentid;
public String ecpm;
}

class Error {

public String error;
}
```

Result of running this code:

```
Json [url_click=null, url_img=null, url_show=null, imgsize=null, cntr=null, ip=null, version=null]
```

I suppose it's problem with classes, but now idea how to make it work properly. GSON is in version 2.2.2, Java 1.6.

Comment: For me, the results of running your code as currently presented is to get a NullPointerException.

Comment: @shman Bruce's answer will solve your problem. after checking, mark i as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As presented in the original question, the code results in a NullPointerException.  Beyond that...

There are two basic problems with the current deserialization code in the original question:

First, the JSON element names don't match the Java field names, thus Gson cannot automatically databind during deserialization, without additional configuration information -- mapping the JSON elements to the Java fields.  If the Java field names exactly matched the JSON element names, then such additional configuration would not be necessary.  The example below uses the `@SerializedName` annotation to provide the missing name-mappings.

Second, the JSON data structure does not exactly (enough) match the Java data structure.  The JSON includes a collection of "data" objects, while the Java data structure is expecting just one "data" object.  A simple way to correct for this, is to just change the Java structure to match the JSON, and to expect a collection (list or array) of "data" objects, which the example below demonstrates.  (Alternatively, simple custom deserialization processing could be used to bind the JSON collection (of one component) to a Java field that is not a collection.)

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Json j = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), Json.class);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(j));
  }
}

class Json
{
  @SerializedName("data")
  public List<Data> d;

  @SerializedName("error")
  public Error r;
}

class Data
{
  public static String url_click;
  public String url_img;
  public String url_show;
  public String imgsize;
  public String cntr;
  public String ip;
  public String version;
  public String browser;
  public String agent;
  public List<Campaign> campaign;
}

class Campaign
{
  public String banner_type;
  public String campaign_type;
  public String cid;
  public String contentid;
  public String ecpm;
}

class Error
{
  public String error;
}
```

Also, note that mapping a static Java member to a field in a collection of JSON objects is at least a conceptual/semantic mismatch.  It's not the worst thing to do.  Just be sure it's understood what it means.

Comment: your solution works fine. Just one suggestion. We can avoid class `Error` by using just `String` over there